# Shortcode to embend youtube video in native way

Tags: function, youtube, shortcode

I use custom WP Theme with sidebars made in Elementor. I have multiple sidebars with multiple youtube videos, places whit urls in just plane text (in text block). That's where the built-in function of wordpress to turn the links into embedded videos intervenes, after which WP-Rocket turns them into simple images with a play button (lazy loading).

I want to make a shortcode to put in the places where I want to change the videos and this shortcode to put the link to work as described above.

I've tried a simple shortcode that just returns text, but no luck - it doesn't convert to an embedded video.

I tried the following code, it loads the video, but then the WP-Rocket lazy loading doesn't activate.

```php
function video_shortcode1( $atts ) {
    return wp_video_shortcode( array( 'type' => 'video/youtube' , 'src' => 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydZit1jcG8c' ) );
}
add_shortcode( 'video_sbar1', 'video_shortcode1' );
```

Could you help with this puzzle?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code, that use `wp_oembed_get`:

```php
function youtube_embed_shortcode1() {
  // YT link here 
  $video_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ';

  return wp_oembed_get($video_url);
}

add_shortcode('ytsbar1', 'youtube_embed_shortcode1');
```